# Rails, ActiveRecord multiple query results in one instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, will-paginate

What I'm trying to accomplish (if it's possible) is to create a query that will essentially do 2 searches and return the results into one instance variable.  The reason for this is because, I am using the `will_paginate` gem and it only allows me to render an array of objects from the single query and doesn't accept anything else to be pushed onto that array being sent to the template.

i.e.

My `events_controller.rb`

```
#returns all events that match query
@events_search_result = Events.search(params[:event][:query])

#returns all events where column 'repeats' is nil
@events_not_repeat = Events.where.not(repeats: nil)
@events_not_repeat.each do |event|
  #'schedule.occurs_on?' methods coming from different gem. Not relative in the outcome of the array of objects to be rendered. 
  if event.schedule.occurs_on?(params)
    @events_search_result << event
  end
end
```

Pushing these two array of objects gives me the desired result, but when trying to render `@events_search_result` to the template, I get the error...

`NoMethodError - undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Array:0x00000000>:`
Which is coming from the `will_paginate` gem.

Ideally, I'd like the two queries to happen in one shot, which is what I believe will solve my issue.  I've looked at the `ActiveRecord Query Interface` but due to my inexperience, I'm not that familiar with the query combinations that can be achieved.

Any advice will help a lot. Been stuck on this issue for quite a while now and tried a bunch of workarounds. Apologize in advance if my examples aren't descriptive enough but I'd be happy to fill in the details if need be. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check whether it worked with just one query result? . I don't see any problem in appending the result set of another query.

Comment: I did.  I works on one result but as soon as I push something onto it. It throws the error above. @BinaryMee

Comment: Do you have a `has_one` relationship of `Schedule` model with `Events` model ?

Comment: Could you show us how you are paginating?

Comment: The `schedule` model I don't belive needs a relationship. Its coming from the `ice_cube` gem which is a way to create recurring events from inside your `events` model. What were you thinking, I'm curious. @AmitThawait

Comment: Sure.  `Event.search(params).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)` @BinaryMee

Comment: The problem you are facing is obvious : since `total_pages` method is available on `Will::Paginate` collection object. When you add objects using `<<`, the `Will::Paginate` collection object gets converted into Array, hence the error. I was tried to create a single query that will give you a `Will::Paginate` collection object.

Comment: Correct. However I still need the result from the first query and second query to be sent to the template. Can this be achieved through a single dynamic query?@AmitThawait

Comment: Yes posted my answer. In this case you cannot make single query, since you have dependency on ice_cube gem

Comment: You may want to use [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) instead of that `each` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Since your both objects are of same model, you can add one object to other and apply pagination.

for eg:

```
  @events_search_result = Events.search(params[:event][:query])
  @events_not_repeat = Events.where.not(repeats: nil)
  @combined_events = @events_search_result + @events_not_repeat
  @combined_events.apply_will_paginate
```

Comment: OK I see. I tried something similar in my `event.rb`. Is `apply_wil_paginate` a `will_paginate` method? @Chitrank Samaiya

Answer (score 0):

You need to require `will_paginate/array` in your will_paginate initializer file to fix your issue :

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the instance variable being sent to the template call ...
`@combined_events_of_both_queries.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)` to change it to a `will_paginate` array to be iterated over.